# JQuery .change() how to get value

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am implementing dynamic drop-down selectors using JQuery. I am new to frontend in general. I am struggling to access the value that a dropdown has changed to when I use JQuery.

The user journey is (1) pick a 'collection' and then (2) from within that collection, pick a 'unit'.

I implemented the 'collection' dropdown onchange attribute in HTML like this:

```
<select name="collection" id="collection" onchange="collectionChanged(this.value)">
```

With this method, the collectionChanged function gets the value that the dropdown selected has changed to. I then tried to implement the 'unit' onchange behaviour with JQuery. But I get an object that doesn't have a value attribute or anything that looks comparable. I looked at the documentation at the [JQuery Website](https://api.jquery.com/change/) and also at [W3CSchools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp). In both cases, the functions they use do not take any arguments, so I have nothing to compare to. What am I missing?

```
function getOrCreateUnitSelect() {
    let unitSelect;
    if ( ! unitSelectExists() ) {
        unitSelect = $('<select />', {"id": "unit-select"});

        // This is where I add the 'on change' function
        unitSelect.change(unitChanged);
        unitSelect.insertAfter($('#collection'));
    }
    else {
        unitSelect = $('#unit-select');
    }
    return unitSelect;
}

function unitSelectExists() {
    return $('#unit-select').length;
}

function collectionChanged(value) {
    let processFilterResponse = function(serverResponseData, textStatusIgnored, jqXHRIgnored) {
        let serverDataObject = JSON.parse(serverResponseData);

        let unitSelect = getOrCreateUnitSelect();

        serverDataObject['content']['units'].forEach(
            function(unit){
                $(
                    "<option />",
                    {value: unit, text: unit}
                    ).appendTo($("#unit-select"));
                        }
        );
        }

    let config = {
        type: "GET",
        url: filterUrl,
        data: {'collection': value},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: processFilterResponse
    }
    $.ajax(config);
}


function unitChanged(e) {
    console.log("unit has been changed");
    // Here I get some object that doesn't have a 'value' attribute
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Please also upvote Ryan's answer as he pointed out an error in my answer, and he was absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `.change` calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered, so in `unitChanged(e)` you can just do `console.log(this.value)`.

Note: `.change(handler)` is just shorthand for `.on("change", handler)`

Comment: Thank you Ryan. I didn't realize that `.change()` is jQuery shorthand for jQuery `.on( "change", handler )`. Well done. +1